# Disable console logs for GhostDriver, PhantomJS with WebdriverJS

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver, webdriverjs

I have been trying to figure out how to **disable** the annoying console logs when we run phantomjs(ghost driver) with webdriverjs but in vain.

```
[INFO  - 2016-10-09T14:57:15.039Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 62381
[INFO  - 2016-10-09T14:57:15.084Z] Session [aa75cc80-8e30-11e6-8da5-a561819d4151] - page.settings - {"XSSAuditingEnabled":false,"javascriptCanCloseWindows":true,"javascriptCanOpenWindows":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"loadImages":true,"localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled":false,"userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/2.1.1 Safari/538.1","webSecurityEnabled":true}
[INFO  - 2016-10-09T14:57:15.084Z] Session [aa75cc80-8e30-11e6-8da5-a561819d4151] - page.customHeaders:  - {}
[INFO  - 2016-10-09T14:57:15.084Z] Session [aa75cc80-8e30-11e6-8da5-a561819d4151] - Session.negotiatedCapabilities - {"browserName":"phantomjs","version":"2.1.1","driverName":"ghostdriver","driverVersion":"1.2.0","platform":"mac-10.10 (Yosemite)-64bit","javascriptEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"handlesAlerts":false,"databaseEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"browserConnectionEnabled":false,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"webStorageEnabled":false,"rotatable":false,"acceptSslCerts":false,"nativeEvents":true,"proxy":{"proxyType":"direct"}}
[INFO  - 2016-10-09T14:57:15.084Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _postNewSessionCommand - New Session Created: aa75cc80-8e30-11e6-8da5-a561819d4151
```

Following is my configuration:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var phantomjs_exe = require('phantomjs-prebuilt').path;
var customPhantom = webdriver.Capabilities.phantomjs();
customPhantom.set("phantomjs.binary.path", phantomjs_exe);

//build custom phantomJS driver
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
             withCapabilities(customPhantom).
             build();
```

Things done from my side -

- Went through various SO threads but all of them had solutions/methods in java api bindings.I am looking for nodejs solutions. following are the things suggested :
- `Logger.getLogger(PhantomJSDriverService.class.getName()).setLevel(Level.OFF)`
- Silence ghostdriver.log

  ```
  import os
  driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_log_path=os.path.devnull);
  ```
- Using Desired Capabilities:

  ```
  DesiredCapabilities dcap = new DesiredCapabilities();
  String[] phantomArgs = new  String[] {"--webdriver-loglevel=NONE"};
  dcap.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, phantomArgs);
  PhantomJSDriver phantomDriver = new PhantomJSDriver(dcap);
  ```

How can I do them in **nodejs** webdriver api bindings?? can anyone guide in the right direction? I find very few api doc examples which are not useful!